# Windows 10 LTSB does not activate automatically from KMS

Tags: windows-10

I have an issue related to automatic Windows 10 LTSB KMS activation, however when trying to activate it manually with command line using slmgr.vbs, it activates very smoothly.
I do believe I have something wrong with Windows 10 LTSB itself rather than KMS server but I cannot figure out the cause behind this case.